# NVCC 5.0 and OpenACC

Tags: cuda, nvcc, openacc

According to [NVIDIA website](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit):

> "The CUDA Toolkit complements and fully supports programming with
> OpenACC directives."

Does this mean OpenACC programs (pargma and API) can be compiled with `nvcc` compiler? Or it means only runtime routine calls are supported?

Unfortunately, I cannot install CUDA Toolkit 5.0 atm to get my answer. Thanks!

Comment: At the present time you need an [openACC compliant compiler](https://developer.nvidia.com/openacc) from CAPS, PGI, or Cray.  The CUDA toolkit by itself does not allow you to compile directives.

Comment: Thanks Robert! The term `support` at the nvidia page is really confusing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To compile a program using OpenACC directives, you need to use an [OpenACC compiler](https://developer.nvidia.com/openacc) - currently that means Cray, PGI or CAPS.

Parts of the CUDA Toolkit are used by the OpenACC compilers, depending on the implementation they can use various components such as `ptxas` to assemble PTX to the machine code. The Toolkit also includes libraries such as cuBLAS/cuFFT/cuSPARSE etc. which can interoperate with OpenACC so that you can use both libraries and OpenACC in the same app - you can also interoperate with CUDA C/C++.

`nvcc` itself is not an OpenACC compiler.

Comment: Note that if you're interested in playing with OpenACC, you can get a 30 day trial (last time I tried it was 15 days renewable once) of the PGI OpenACC compiler here: https://www.pgroup.com/account/register.php?openacc_user

Comment: Also note that the NVIDIA Visual Profiler will work with PGI OpenACC compiler generated code. I haven't personally tried Cray or CAPS compilers with nvvp, so can't comment about those.

Answer (score 0):

There exists [accULL](http://accull.wordpress.com/), The OpenACC research implementation (C only, OpenACC 1.0).